# Bootstrap 3 Bleed left and right background images to edge of browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve.  The top box with a background image that spans the whole browser width, and 2 content boxes inside centered.  I've done that no problem.

I then need want 2 more boxes underneath, again centered, but each half needs a different backgkround image that should meet in the middle and bleed of to their respective edge.  I am using bootstrap becuase I want these to stack on smaller screens.  I can't figure out how this is possible.  the black border represents the container.  I can wrap the top bit in its own container which is fine, but I can't work out how to get the bottom bit to work, and I don't really want to use absolute positioning because it'll be a nightmare to get the responsive element to work.

Here is what I have so far

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fluid-full">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="example">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="example">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 left-half">
            <div class="example">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 right-half">
            <div class="example">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.example{
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;

}
.fluid-full{
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/400);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

    }
.left-half{

    border-left: 25% solid transparent;
     background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/400);
      background-position: right;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

}
```

Checkout this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jbExJxEn2C#)

I need the top and bottom boxes to line up.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This cannot be achieved using only Bootstrap classes.
You have to create custom classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've done it.  Had to use some media queries.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fluid-full">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="example">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="example">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid about-us">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sec-title text-center work-with-us">
                <h2>Work With Us</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sec-title text-center what-we-do">
                <h2>What We Do</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example{
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;

}
.fluid-full{
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/400);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

}
.about-us .col-md-6 {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/400);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 70px 0;
}
.about-us .col-md-6 .sec-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.about-us .col-md-6 .sec-title h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.about-us .col-md-6 .sec-title h2::after {
  width: 70px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .about-us .col-md-6 .sec-title {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .about-us .col-md-6 .sec-title {
    width: 455px;
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .about-us .col-md-6 .sec-title {
    width: 555px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .about-us .col-md-6 .work-with-us {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/KNEobzBXCi)

Hopefully this might be useful to someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

I took you Bootply example and modified bottom bit to this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 fluid-half">
  <div class="example col-md-6 pull-right"> 
    <h1 class="text-center">LEFT</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 fluid-half">
  <div class="example col-md-6 pull-left">
    <h1 class="text-center">RIGHT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [Bootply modification](http://www.bootply.com/zgecc5qsaP)

Is this something you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @nrvnm this is very close, but I would like the bottom 2 boxes to be the same width as the ones on top.  Bu this is closer than I got.

Comment: Is it absolute must that you need to do it by using purely bootstrap, or I can tweak the css?

Comment: How about this version. The boxes will stay the same, however the background behind is bound by container. If you fill the rest with grey color, it looks fine. This method depends on your background images. http://www.bootply.com/r4PYrtuU3p#

Comment: No it doesn't have to be bootstrap, but they need to be responsive, and stack on mobile.